# How to perform action on parent class when changing an attribute of an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I want to perform an action on an outer class, demonstrated in this minimal example with `self.item = 0`, when an attribute of an attribute is set.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Inner:
    attr: int


class Outer:
    _inner: Inner
    item: int
    def __init__(self, inner: Inner) -> None:
        self._inner = inner
        self.item = 1

    @property
    def inner(self):
        return self._inner
    
    @inner.setter
    def inner(self, value):
        self.item = 0
        self._inner = value


test = Outer(inner = Inner(attr = 1))

test.inner.attr = 2
print(test.item)
```

The result of the above test shows that self.item is still 0, as only the getter is called and not the setter. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `self.inner = inner` to use the setter, not `self._inner = inner`

Comment: If you rename _inner to inner this just leads to recursion for me, as then the property tries to return itself - if you have a fully working test though please do post it below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presented below are two solutions to this problem - they work best in different scenarios so I thought I would present both.

**Solution 1: The Python Way**

I placed this solution first because I believe it applies in all cases, for all data structures of inner, although it may be wished to be avoided in some circumstances:

```py
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Inner:
    attr: int

    def _supply_callback(self, callback):
        self._callback = callback

    def __setattr__(self, __name: str, __value: Any) -> None:
        if hasattr(self, '_callback'):
            self._callback()
        super().__setattr__(__name, __value)



class Outer:
    _inner: Inner
    item: int
    def __init__(self, inner: Inner) -> None:
        def reset_item():
            self.item = 0
        inner._supply_callback(callback = reset_item)
        self._inner = inner
        self.item = 1

    @property
    def inner(self):
        return self._inner
    
    @inner.setter
    def inner(self, value):
        self.item = 0
        self._inner = value


test = Outer(inner = Inner(attr = 1))
print(test.item)
print(test.inner.attr)
test.inner.attr = 2
print(test.item)
print(test.inner.attr)
```

**Solution 2: The Pydantic Way**

It so happens that I'm using [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) for my model anyway, so a second way occurred to me. You may find this method to be more explicit if you don't want to override `__setattr__`. The syntax `validator('*')` here just means validate all attributes:

```py
from typing import Callable, ClassVar, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Inner(BaseModel):
    attr: int
    _callback: ClassVar[Optional[Callable[[], None]]] = None

    @classmethod
    def _supply_callback(cls, callback):
        cls._callback = callback
        return cls

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True

    @validator('*')
    def run_callback(cls, v):
        if cls._callback is not None:
            cls._callback()
        return v


class Outer:
    _inner: Inner
    item: int
    def __init__(self, inner: Inner) -> None:
        def reset_item():
            self.item = 0
        inner._supply_callback(callback = reset_item)
        self._inner = inner
        self.item = 1

    @property
    def inner(self):
        return self._inner
    
    @inner.setter
    def inner(self, value):
        self.item = 0
        self._inner = value


test = Outer(inner = Inner(attr = 1))
print(test.item)
print(test.inner.attr)
test.inner.attr = 2
print(test.item)
print(test.inner.attr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I have a solution of sorts - can't say I'm too pleased with it, as it means defining setters for all the attrs of Inner (which in the real case there are many)

```py
from typing import Callable

class Inner:
    _attr: int
    _callback: Callable[[], None]
    def __init__(self, attr: int) -> None:
        self._attr = attr

    def _supply_callback(self, callback):
        self._callback = callback

    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr
    
    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        self._callback()
        self._attr = value


class Outer:
    _inner: Inner
    item: int
    def __init__(self, inner: Inner) -> None:
        def reset_item():
            self.item = 0
        inner._supply_callback(callback = reset_item)
        self._inner = inner
        self.item = 1

    @property
    def inner(self):
        return self._inner
    
    @inner.setter
    def inner(self, value):
        self.item = 0
        self._inner = value


test = Outer(inner = Inner(attr = 1))
print(test.item)
print(test.inner.attr)
test.inner.attr = 2
print(test.item)
print(test.inner.attr)
```